# Converting string to json with Okhttp

Tags: android, api, url, post, token

First of all, I have been searching for an answer and none works actually, API is ok, url is ok.

I have a method builder which contructs an url and an API name, it was working fine, but one of the API sould attach the token in the url and the params via post, I have the trouble there

Post method I'm using

```
public Heap post(String... params) throws ApiException {
    Heap answer = new Heap();
    StringBuilder listedParams = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i < params.length - 1; i++) {
        listedParams.append(params[i]);
    }
    try {
        answer = new Heap(new JSONObject(new AsyncRequest().execute(urlBuildier(params[0]), listedParams.toString(), "post").get()));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return answer;
}
```

urlBuilder method I'm using

```
private String urlBuildier(String... parts) {
    ArrayList<String> params = new ArrayList<>();
    if (assets)
        params.add(urlAssets);
    else
        params.add(url);

    final StringBuilder helper = new StringBuilder();
    Collections.addAll(params, parts);
    Heap built = new Heap(params);
    built.forEach(new Part() {
        @Override
        public void Run(Heap part) {
            helper.append(part.get());
        }
    });
    return helper.toString();
}
```

the async class

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, params[1]);
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .post(body)
                        .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                        .url(params[0])
                        .build();

                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                String responseStrng = response.body().string();
                return responseStrng;
```

The problem ocurrs when the url needs to attach a token, example: 
https://url/api/apiname? This works with my post method

But: https://url/api/apiname?token=abc123 isn't working with my post method.

PDT: the unic thing I changed from the previous methods to work was my post and post async this way:

previus post method

```
public Heap post(String... params) throws ApiException {
    Heap answer = new Heap();
    try {
        answer = new Heap(new JSONObject(new AsyncRequest().execute(urlBuildier(params), "post").get()));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Previous okhttp async

```
final String[] post = params[0].split("[?]");
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, post[1]);
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(post[0])
                        .post(body)
                        .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                        .build();

                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                String responseStrng = response.body().string();
return responseStrng;
```

This is my log:

```
06-02 22:32:04.443 6335-6335/co.cardseed.cardseed W/System.err:   org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be   converted to JSONObject
    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
06-02 22:32:04.444 6335-6335/co.cardseed.cardseed W/System.err:     at co.cardseed.cardseed.app.api.Api.post(Api.java:103)
    at co.cardseed.cardseed.activities.WebActivity.onCreate(WebActivity.java:45)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

I would apreciate any help.

Comment: Could you please add the string value of your string you try to parse? It seems like the problem comes from this place

Comment: An update. when I add the long token to the url, the problem triggers, but with things like: token=123, API responds with the usual json.

Comment: what line exactly is "Api.java:103"?

Comment: answer = new Heap(new JSONObject(new AsyncRequest().execute(urlBuildier(params[0]), listedParams.toString(), "post").get()));

That one, I try to convert the async request response to JSONObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, servermaster allow the send of the token via header ant it kinda solves the problem, but in android it never works. Thanks for all.